# Is there a way I can build a project using Laravel, but keep the core files separate from my site's files?

Tags: laravel

I need to be able to set up a new project in Laravel, but to keep the original Laravel files intact while I code my site.

Any actual site-specific code (config/controllers/templates/etc) will need to be in a separate area/directory, one that won't be touched if I ever need to swap out the laravel install for an updated version.

Is this possible?

Comment: That's how Laravel always works, at least in version 4. Installing via Composer puts the Laravel files in the `vendor` directory, where they're left untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is made of two separate layers:

```
core framework vendor (with dependencies)
application layer
```

Core framework is a base of everything what is happening in your app. Application is just a well designed and structured layer, that can be thrown away and replaced with your version. Ofcourse, if you know what you are doing. Application is made with best practices involved so changing it is not recommended. To proof, take a look at official Laravel repo at github.There you will find that core and application are separated and can be cloned independently. The best possible example can be found in a core framework tests directory. There Taylor Otwell actually created and test application without application layer. Something like headless laravel application. For me it was great learning experience to read those tests.
Also Laravel is created  and structured with best object-oriented practices. It is loosely coupled, with IoC contatiner, facades... So you can rearrange it the way you want it.

Comment: This is interesting. Is this https://github.com/laravel/framework the core framework that you mentioned? So I can clone this (or define it as a dependency in my own composer file) and have my own app directory/layer? Then when Laravel is updated I can just pull changes from the core framework repo.

Comment: Yes.Think of application layer as kind of interface to Laravel.
In order to work with Laravel through that interface (application)
you'll have to "fine tune" a lot of things. Core framework is just a group of related classes,files and namespaces. Application serves as a glue that ties everything together. You can write your own glue.
Without application and bootstrap process you don't have much - no service providers,no facades, no db configuration, no route file...
Without app, you have just a raw framework that does nothing.

Comment: I understand. That's such a good approach. The app layer that Laravel provides seems very lightweight anyway, so I'd base my own off that and just tweak some configuration. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is completely possible. Have a look at the [package development](http://laravel.com/docs/packages) documentation.

If you want to see an example here is a repo I have been working on that started out as a package and moved to a composer package: [wardrobecms/cabinet](https://github.com/wardrobecms/cabinet) It is in development so I doubt you could run it but you should be able to see how it's setup.

Comment: This is really helpful! The reason I'm asking is that I'm producing an in-house codebase/CMS for use at the company I work for. There'll be the core CMS (installed via composer like yours is hopefully) and then a bunch of internal dependencies for other functionality. Were there any specific resources you found while making your CMS that you could recommend?